# Is there a Tolkien "church"?

Tags: j-r-r-tolkien, influences

I once remember, long ago, finding a "church" that believes Tolkien wasn't writing fiction, but history, as archangel Gabriel dictated it to him. This "church" believes that everything Tolkien wrote chronologically happened before the Great Flood. They consider *The Silmarillion* a holy book and *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings* historical fiction, but reliable historical fiction.

This was a long time ago, some 5-6 years ago, and I can't find this "church" anywhere. My question is, does something like this exist anywhere else?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/First-Church-of-Tolkien-216937048407489/ ?

Comment: A group of people taking a fantasy/science fiction authors works, and then forming a religion based on it. I can't see any money in that at all. :)

Comment: Richard C, no, they BELIEVE it. They claimed one guy talked with Tolkien and Tolkien told him that archangel Gabriel appeared to him and dictated him pre-Flood history. My question is, why didn't Tolkien mentioned that?:)

Comment: I believe Tolkien has been pretty clear, over the course of something like 20 or 30 years worth of correspondence, what is what. I think the most that can be said for any kind of 'direct inspiration' of the spiritual sort is that he, as a youth, had "Atlantis dreams" -- dreams of being overtaken by a huge flood. I am reasonably certain that whoever said that Gabriel dictated the story to him has been in the pipeweed too much. I should think that Gabriel would soon tire of Tolkien's incessant and compulsive need to write, correct, revise, recorrect & rewrite just about every word written!

Comment: Man I wish that LOTR was a true story lol

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, at least, I once posited that *[Iluvatarism](https://cbb.aveneca.com/viewtopic.php?t=6904#p289478)* would be that religion.  There is certainly enough matter in the legendarium to put together a sort of basic theistic religion. More, certainly, than the adherents of [Jediism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jediism) have available to them.

One problem in research is that most of the terms one might consider tend to crop up as fan-fic in-world religions. That is, religions purportedly followed by peoples within Middle Earth itself. I have read some forum posts, usually in Tolkien fan groups, that seem indicative of at least a few individuals have tried to create (usually quite bizarre) religious paths out of it.

Either way, I am certain Mr Tolkien would have rolled his eyes in disgust at the very notion of people taking his work and so abusing it.

Comment: The religion would simply be Christianity, since it is literally true in Tolkien’s universe, just with some imaginary history added.

Comment: @Shamshiel That's some pretty weird Christianity, I think. I woulda read the Bible a lot earlier if it had giant spiders invading the land of the gods.

Comment: @MishaR reading the letters lays this out pretty clearly.

Comment: @Shamshiel I think that we should be more careful about separating Tolkien's letters from his legendarium.  There is a reason he did not include *any* actual Christianity in his books, and we should respect that.  He may have ruminated on it in his letters - and his self-analysis may lay it out clearly, but the enormous number of differences between the books and Christianity is no less clear.  Let's give Tolkien a little breathing room, shall we.  It's like saying that an atheist cannot create a fictional world that has gods in it, just because of their thoughts on what it means for atheism.

Comment: Some interesting but extended discussion about Tolkien and religion; I've left the first few comments and [moved the rest to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104551/discussion-on-answer-by-elemtilas-is-there-a-tolkien-church). Please continue the conversation there.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - The rest of the comments really should be placed in chat as well. Now that they're out of context, they don't make a lot of sense here!

Comment: @elemtilas The comments I left are largely the *first* ones posted, so they have as much context as they had originally; it's the extended follow-ups that went to chat. (All of them are copied to chat though; just not all deleted here.)